Could not dynamically require
I write electron applications using typescript, vite and react. I also want to use sqlite (the application should run locally). I found a great ORM (Drizzle), but I have a problem with the libSQL driver. When I try to run it, I get this error:
Could not dynamically require "@libsql/win32-x64-msvc". Please configure the dynamicRequireTargets or/and ignoreDynamicRequires option of @rollup/plugin-commonjs appropriately for this require call to work.
The alternative is better-sqlite3 but this driver does not work at all (better sqlite 3 __filename error)
I've been fighting with this all day, nothing works, I can't find ANY, I really mean ANY information/solutions.
Please help, you are my last resort.
I already tried to add dynamicRequireTargets, but no with no results
vite-config.ts
import path from "node:path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import electron from "vite-plugin-electron/simple";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
    alias: [
      {
        find: "@components",
        replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/renderer/components")
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    commonjs(),
    react(),
    electron({
      main: {
        // Shortcut of `build.lib.entry`.
        entry: "src/main/main.ts"
      },
      preload: {
        // Shortcut of `build.rollupOptions.input`.
        // Preload scripts may contain Web assets, so use the `build.rollupOptions.input` instead `build.lib.entry`.
        input: path.join(__dirname, "src/main/preload.ts")
      },
      // Ployfill the Electron and Node.js API for Renderer process.
      // If you want use Node.js in Renderer process, the `nodeIntegration` needs to be enabled in the Main process.
      // See  https://github.com/electron-vite/vite-plugin-electron-renderer
      renderer: process.env.NODE_ENV === "test"
        // https://github.com/electron-vite/vite-plugin-electron-renderer/issues/78#issuecomment-2053600808
        ? undefined
        : {}
    })
  ],
  build: {
    commonjsOptions: {
      dynamicRequireTargets: ["@libsql/win32-x64-msvc"]
    }
  }
});

I also tried
commonjs({
  commonjsOptions: {
    dynamicRequireTargets: ["@libsql/win32-x64-msvc"]
  }
})


Where are you calling it? From where is the error thrown?

@Arkellys That doesn't matter from where i call it cause its always drop error, but i call it inside main electron file, and error is from main.js from electron dist

Yes it matters, because it's not clear how you get this error.
